# SSRS Is there a way to set a dropdown null check mark as default?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRgmJ.png)I have 3 dropdowns and i want 1 dropdown set null check mark by default.
So only when needed to filter with marriedname the check mark can be removed.
Dropdown are Names, Firstnames and Marriedname.

Dataset Marriedname:

`Select distinct [Name3]
from Patient
ORDER BY [Name3]`

Answer (score 0):

Go to your parameter properties (Marriedname). If you tick the checkbox "Allow null value", there will be a null check mark and it will be checked by default when you run the report.

edit: The "null" checkbox will not show up if the parameter available values are populated from a dataset. Workaround is to include the "null" value as one of the options in the dropdown list from the dataset results. This query will add a null value to your result set in the dropdown and you can specify the null value by default.

```
Select distinct [Name3]  
into #temptable
from PatientenNAW  
ORDER BY [Name3] 

insert into #temptable ([Name3]) values (null) --you might need to put this null value in single quotes depending on how you reference default value

drop table #temptable
```

Comment: Hi i'm using get values from a query instead of specify value.

Comment: Why doesn't the null checkbox work? If you want the "null" to be in the dropdown list, you can try this: add your query into a temp table, then insert a "null" row into the temp table. In your default value for this parameter, you can set it to the value of the null row. If you want the null to be on top or bottom of your dropdown list, then you need to add in some kind of sorting to your query.

Comment: Hi i've tick the "allow null value ". And default values is "(Null)". still the checkbox isn't showing. It gives me a error when i run the report if i don't select a marriedname, although i have selected a name and firstname.

Comment: I did some researching and it turns out it will not show the null checkbox if you are populating the available values with a query. One workaround is to have the null value included in the result of your query and you can use the steps I mentioned in the previous comment with the temp table to achieve that.

Comment: Hi do you have a example of a temp table query and how i can insert the null?

Comment: Can you edit your original question to include a sample of your query and what you are using for label/value in the parameter, I will try to edit my response to include your the query.

Comment: I'm stuck with the query can you help? create table temp(Marriedname(varchar(max))
insert into temptable (Marriedname)
Select distinct [Name3]
from PatientenNAW
ORDER BY [Name3]

insert into temptable values(null)

Comment: Yes i have placed the query in the original question.

Comment: I'm getting a error when running the report: 'Failed to preview report. The report parameter 'Marriedname' uses the field 'Name3' in a dataset reference, but the dataset 'DropdownGehuwdnaam' does not contain that field.

Comment: This is unrelated to particular issue. You want to make sure your dataset executes and returns expected result, I reference Name3 column because this is in your original query. Once you get it working, you just need to replace Name3 with whatever the proper column name is.

Comment: Hi it's working now i add " alter TABLE tempMarriedname  ALTER COLUMN Name3 varchar(30)NULL" in the query and it's working. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps will help you get your desired result.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi in report parameter properties: in  "Available values" i have a dataset. The query is to generate marriednames. And Default values has a value null.

Comment: yes that's fine, I was just showing how to do it and do not worry about `just null value` in your case it will be simply null. Do you still face issue doing changes as mentioned or you managed to solve it?